# STM32F105RB GPIO PB8 PB15 PB9 and PB3 Toggles together

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide, stm32f1, truestudio

please.
I am having weird behavior with STM32F105RB (64pins) board, the issue is on GPIO PB8, PB15, PB9 and PB3.

```
GPIO_InitTypeDef  BOARDPINS;
RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOB, ENABLE);
BOARDPINS.GPIO_Pin=(GPIO_Pin_9);
BOARDPINS.GPIO_Mode=GPIO_Mode_Out_PP;
BOARDPINS.GPIO_Speed=GPIO_Speed_2MHz;
GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &BOARDPINS);
DISABLEJTAG();
```

**The Problem:**
Each time i configured one of these as OUTPUT PUSH PULL (PB8, PB15, PB9, PB3) and toggle a pin, they all act like there is a shot circuit. all these three pins will toggle together.
**My Diagnosis:**
I tested for continuity (shot circuit) among these pins by taking off power and physically test pair of these GPIOs. but no shot was detected.

I checked the datasheet and reference manual but did not see any special feature associated with these pins.
Every other pin with exception of these four toggles individually, no issue.
My based IDE is Truestudio 9.3.0, i tried using eclipse with arm plugins and also tried Arduiono 1.18.19. none got it solved.

**Now, I am asking**
What could be wrong?
Is there feature is need to disable?

Comment: Are definitions correct? What is the value of GPIO_Pin_9? It seems to apply the same setting to multiple pins then. This is not an expected behavior, and the only source of problem is 100% in software.

Comment: The value of GPIO_Pin_9 is default, it is defined in truestudio. 
so,  i did not define it myself.

Comment: You didn't answer the question. Not everyone has truestudio. It's not about IDE.